# How to create a paginated slideshow from blog posts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, pagination

For a dashboard information display that we will put in the lobby I am aggregating data from various sources. One of the sources is our company's blog. What I want to do is show the latest two blog posts on the dashboard in a nice paginated way. What I already have is a database containing the blog posts and a codeigniter (PHP framework) view that shows a blog post in the dashboard.

Of course the blog posts can have an arbitrary length and I want people to read them on a television screen. So they have to be paginated in a nice way. It would be great if there was a jQuery plugin or the like that takes a piece of HTML, determines how much of it (including images) fits inside the parent div without scrolling and then paginates from there, refreshing to the next page after a while.

Now my question is two-fold: would you recommend paginating the posts server-side or client side (I guess I would prefer client-side in this case)? And what is the best way to do it? If you could recommend a plugin and give an example that would be great.

UPDATE: still looking for a solution and in addition we would want it to work on a smart TV browser.

Comment: Question just to be sure- you want to "split" post that is too long to show whole content on screen, and paginate its parts right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The difficulty (and difference to other questions about this) is that I want to split based on displayed height, instead of just a number of words/lines.